# Angular: On focus not getting triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
const events = [
    'input',
    'focus'
];
const eventStreams = events.map((ev) =>
    Observable.fromEvent(this.inputElem.nativeElement, ev).map((event) => 
    event['target'].value).debounceTime(this.delay).distinctUntilChanged()
  );
const allEvents$ = Observable.merge(...eventStreams);

this.subscription = allEvents$.subscribe((input) => {
  this.showSuggestions = true;
  this.inputChange.emit(input);  
});

if (this.SuggestionsOverlayElem) {
  this.styleSuggestionOverlay();
}
```

*onfocus* is only working for the first time, but it does not get triggered
if I focus multiple times. But it should trigger every time whenever I
focus on text input.

Comment: ```.distinctUntilChanged()``` this prevents event from triggering if input value was not changed

Comment: is `input` event triggered multiple times?

Comment: Could you add a little more code so that we can attempt to recreate your situation?